# Are there legal remedies to noise from thin walls?

Tags: rental-property, noise

I rent a second-floor bedroom. The landlord's family lives on the third floor. The ceiling is not very soundproof: If they are walking around the sound of footsteps is loud enough to prevent me from sleeping.

Does a tenant have any rights to any level of quiet?

Comment: It may in part depend on the nature of the activity producing the footsteps and the time at which you are trying to sleep.  It almost certainly depends on the jurisdiction.

Comment: the upstairs family frequently make noises after 12am, midnight. The sound of footsteps is very loud and can be clearly heard after midnight. I mean that between 12am to 7 am, it is reasonable to maintain a quiet environment.

Comment: That's absolutely true, but it probably also depends a bit on how much walking they're doing.  If it's a half an hour of constant pacing, you have a much better position than if it's a couple of trips from the bed to the bathroom.  You still haven't told us the jurisdiction.

Comment: It sounds like you're renting a single room within a house - is that accurate?  Did you sign any type of tenant agreement, and (more importantly) did the people living above you (guessing not, since landlord's family)? Also, have you tried addressing this with the landlord?  Lastly, where is this?  City ordinances and legal precedences may apply.

Comment: Its difficult for anyone to answer without knowing where you are from.  Generally, tenants have a right to "quiet enjoyment' of the property [ this does NOT literally mean it needs to be quiet, just that they can't be unreasonably disturbed ].  Your remedy is probably to move out and find somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks all of you! actually the children jump frequently(sometimes 3-5 minutes continuously, sometimes more than 5times in one hour) and heavily on the floor and make great noises.